# Where is the ruin in District 13 in The Hunger Games Mockingjay Part I located in real life?

Tags: the-hunger-games, real-location

Am watching the Hunger Games Mockingjay Part I and was struck by the beauty of the location where the picture below is from. In the film it's at 59:03 minutes in, where Gale and Katniss get to go hunting above ground for the first time in District 13.

I would love to visit this location myself in real life so if somebody knows the exact location where the filming of this scene took place.

[image: Gale and Katniss at the ruin in District 13]

Comment: [Try this one](https://www.hostelworld.com/blog/how-to-find-every-single-hunger-games-location-in-real-life) my fav holidays is participating in organized tours to the locations were the games were held. The food, as promised, is excellent.

Answer (score 18):

This article ([Jennifer Lawrence Almost Dies On MockingJay Set In Atlanta](http://www.gafollowers.com/jennifer-lawrence-almost-dies-mockingjay-set-atlanta/)) shows Jennifer Lawrence in front of the archway you took screenshot of.

[image]

On further digging, the above location is in **Sweetwater Creek state park**  [See this link](http://www.asimplerdesign.com/blog/2014/11/21/on-the-set-of-mockingjay-mill-ruins-at-sweetwater-creek)

[The Hunger Games: Mockingjay - Part 1](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1951265/locations) IMDB filming locations also shows  Bellwood Quarry, Atlanta, Georgia, USA as District 13 exterior for any other places you may be interested in, which is about 19 miles away from Sweetwater Creek state park.